# Devise yielding password in plain text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I just stumpled upon something strange while writing specs for my User model (using Devise 4.2.0):

```
password = 'password'
user = User.create!(email: 'test@test.dk', password: password)

user.password
# => 'password'
```

How is this even possible?

Its not visible in the create statement:

```
 SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "test@test.dk"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$11$J.VxqiCi/4uJP/RPbz9EFe48qMiYKU5QJtn.7zlxNd5RJ/JLTfFd6"], ["created_at", 2016-10-11 09:48:50 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-10-11 09:48:50 UTC]]
```

But nevertheless accessible from the console?

Anyone who can shed some light on whats happening here?

Comment: I'm guessing it's because the attribute is set as you're creating the user.  I would assume if you now do `user = User.find_by(email: 'test@test.dk')` then `user.password` you'd get nil

Comment: @j-dexx Thats true. I was just puzzled why it would show. But it seems to be alright.